# I get duplicated results whenever I try to find min & max

Tags: mongodb

> I get duplicated results whenever I try to find min & max using mongoose, I also tried sorting the database then limiting it to the first element same problem what can I do to get only one answer?
> Thanks

```
const minAndMax = await Product.aggregate([{
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "max": { "$max": "$price" },
            "min": { "$min": "$price" }
        }
    }])
console.log(minAndMax);
```

```
//Results

{
  price: 1,
  qty: 23,
  desc: '',
  country: '',
  isDiscount: false,
  discount: null,
  seen: 0,
  _id: 614355236f279d3d886f90e4,
  product: 'A',
  co: 'Samsung',
  cat: 'LAPTOP',
  image: Binary {
    _bsontype: 'Binary',
    sub_type: 0,
    position: 37,
    buffer: <Buffer 31 36 33 31 38 30 32 36 35 39 32 33 34 31 36 33 31 34 37 34 33 38 33 31 30 33 43 61 70 74 75 72 65 2e 50 4e 47>
  },
  __v: 0
}
{
  price: 1,
  qty: 23,
  desc: '',
  country: '',
  isDiscount: false,
  discount: null,
  seen: 0,
  _id: 614355236f279d3d886f90e4,
  product: 'A',
  co: 'Samsung',
  cat: 'LAPTOP',
  image: Binary {
    _bsontype: 'Binary',
    sub_type: 0,
    position: 37,
    buffer: <Buffer 31 36 33 31 38 30 32 36 35 39 32 33 34 31 36 33 31 34 37 34 33 38 33 31 30 33 43 61 70 74 75 72 65 2e 50 4e 47>
  },
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with `aggregation`. But I know that it gets slow when you have many entries.

You can get the result you need by using a combination of `sort` and `limit`.

```
const min = await Product.find().sort({price: -1}).limit(1)
const max = await Product.find().sort({price: 1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Yea I tried that it's giving me the same results as above.

Comment: Are you sure you have multiple documents with different prices?

Comment: Yes, it's giving me the correct answer it just repeats the answer for some reason.

Comment: So you get both min and max and they are duplicated?